# Display datetime as day for xtick

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following sample codes:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dates = ['01/02/2007 00:02:00','01/02/2007 00:04:00','02/02/2007 
00:02:00','02/02/2007 00:04:00']
x = pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
y = [0.32,0.33,0.32,0.34]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

I would like to have the xtick to be just 'Thu' for 01/02/2007 and 'Fri' for 02/02/2007. What is the best possible way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to change the X-axis format:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dates = ['01/02/2007 00:02:00','01/02/2007 00:04:00','02/02/2007 00:02:00','02/02/2007 00:04:00']
x = pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
y = [0.32,0.33,0.32,0.34]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x,y)

yearsFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%a')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The key idea is to get the dayofweek from the DateTime object, like: `x.dayofweek`. This returns the numeric dayofweek. We can easily get the corresponding name `np.array(['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat', 'Sun'])[x.dayofweek]`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
dates = ['01/02/2007 00:02:00','01/02/2007 00:04:00','02/02/2007 00:02:00','02/02/2007 00:04:00']
x = pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
x_d = np.array(['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat', 'Sun'])[x.dayofweek]
y = [0.32,0.33,0.32,0.34]
ser = pd.Series(y, index=x_d)
ser.plot()
```

[image]